# How does precedence works in rust-peg?

Tags: rust, operator-precedence, peg

I have trouble in understanding `pecedence!` in [rust-peg crate](https://crates.io/crates/peg). Take a look at this code:

```
peg::parser! { grammar example() for str {
    rule letter() -> &'input str = x:$(['a'..='z' | 'A'..='A'])

    rule ident() -> &'input str = x:$(letter()+)

    rule _ = [' ' | '\t' | '\n']*

    rule expr() -> String = precedence! {
        variable:@ _ "=" _ value:(@) {
            format!("assign(&mut {}, {})", variable, value)
        }

        --

        "*" _ x:expr() {
            format!("*{}", x)
        }

        --

        ident:ident() {
            String::from(ident)
        }
    }

    pub rule multiple() -> String = _ expr:expr() ** _ _ {
        expr.join("")
    }
} }

fn main() {
    println!("{}", example::multiple("*a = gg").unwrap());
}
```

It will print `*assign(&mut a, gg)` instead of `assign(&mut *a, gg)`.
Why? I thought that `*` rule has higher precedence than `=`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was typing my question I noticed that `=` looks like `x:@ _ "=" _ y:@`, but `*` like `"*" _ x:expr()`. So I replaced `expr()` to `@`(`"*" _ x:@`) and it worked!
It printed `assign(&mut *a, gg)`, just as I wanted.
I decided to ask & answer that question anyway, maybe it will be useful for someone else :)